# Ignoring the value 0 in an array of ints in java

Tags: java, arrays

Currently, when I am trying to find the lowest value in my array after sorting it into ascending order, my program looks at my array of 100 ints and chooses element 0, however that's always 0 because the array is large. How do I ignore the element 0 in the array so it only focuses on elements I have filled? courseMark and examMark are both static int arrays.

```
static void lowestScore()
{
   System.out.println(courseMark[0] + examMark[0]);
   Arrays.sort(courseMark);
   Arrays.sort(examMark);
   for (int sco : courseMark) 
   {
     System.out.println(sco);
   }
   int x = courseMark[count];
   int y = examMark[count];
   int min = Math.min(x, y);
   System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + min);
```

Comment: Only fill the array with objects you have?

Comment: Elaborate your question more and also tell what is value of count in line int x = courseMark[count];

Comment: do you know about indexes that the Array uses and where they start from. i guess you should read a good tutorial on java for your clarity

Comment: Where is `count` defined?  Would `count` be the total number of marks you have so far?  Let's assume that's the case.  How are you populating the array?  Are you entering one mark at a time?  What you can do is call `Arrays.sort(courseMark, 0, count); Arrays.sort(examMark, 0, count);`.  In this case, it will sort only between the elements of 0 up to `count-1` inclusive.  That way you can just concentrate on the marks you have so far.

Comment: Dear Ray,You are a bloody champ, thankyou very much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the lowest score > 0, you can easily compute it in one pass without sorting:

```
static int lowestGTzero(final int[] data){
  int curLowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  for(final int i : data) if(i < curLowest && i > 0) curLowest = i;
  return curLowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start from element 1 ? I don't quite understand your question but maybe like this?

```
System.out.println(courseMark[1] + examMark[1]);
```